# tripwire segmentation fault after upgradiing to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10 yesterday, tripwire has been segfaulting, both in its filesystem scan and when I run `tripwire --init`.

I get the following when I run `tripwire --init --verbose`

```
Open Source Tripwire(R) 2.4.3.7.0 built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Open Source Tripwire 2.4 Portions copyright 2000-2018 Tripwire, Inc.  Tripwire is a registered
trademark of Tripwire, Inc. This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
for details use --version. This is free software which may be redistributed
or modified only under certain conditions; see COPYING for details.
All rights reserved.
Opening configuration file: /etc/tripwire/tw.cfg
This file is encrypted.

Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/site.key
Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/xxxxxx-local.key
Please enter your local passphrase: 
Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/site.key
Opening policy file: /etc/tripwire/tw.pol
This file is encrypted.
Parsing policy file: /etc/tripwire/tw.pol
Generating the database...
*** Processing Unix File System ***
Processing:  /usr/sbin
--- Generating information for: /usr/sbin
Software interrupt forced exit: Segmentation Fault
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled to no avail.

Followup (added Oct 28, 2020): I decided to build and install from source (available [here](https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source)) and it installed and initialized just fine.

As Sergeant Preston used to say, "This case is closed."

Comment: I have the same issue; it works before upgrading to 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

File or Directory permissions in /usr/sbin is likely causing this.  I had a similar issue with 20.04 where a file with 400 permission was causing this. I simply added the exclusion and it work after updating my twpol.cfg

Comment: Perhaps, though ```tripwire``` had been running successfully on previous incarnations of Ubuntu. And, as I remarked, in my followup, a build from source runs just fine.