# tripwire segmentation fault

Tags: tripwire

Kernel: 5.8.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: i3 4.18
Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)

tripwire works fine on VM but segfaulted on host see below:

I get the following when I run tripwire --init -v

```
sudo tripwire --init -v

Open Source Tripwire(R) 2.4.3.7.0 built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Open Source Tripwire 2.4 Portions copyright 2000-2018 Tripwire, Inc.  Tripwire is a registered
trademark of Tripwire, Inc. This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
for details use --version. This is free software which may be redistributed
or modified only under certain conditions; see COPYING for details.
All rights reserved.
Opening configuration file: /etc/tripwire/tw.cfg
This file is encrypted.

Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/site.key
Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/zika.gattaca.net-local.key
Please enter your local passphrase: 
Opening key file: /etc/tripwire/site.key
Opening policy file: /etc/tripwire/tw.pol
This file is encrypted.
Parsing policy file: /etc/tripwire/tw.pol
Generating the database...
*** Processing Unix File System ***
Processing:  /usr/sbin
--- Generating information for: /usr/sbin
Software interrupt forced exit: Segmentation Fault
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Just in case to prevent you from copy&paste I found myself some answers:

> Hi Shane, couple of things you can try right away --
>
> Your log seems to indicate the init stumbles over something in /proc. If you don't need to scan /proc at all, you can just add a "! /proc ;" line to your policy to exclude it.
>
> Alternately you can try an "--init --verbose", which should tell you which file (or /proc pseudo-file, in this case) it's failing on. If you try this a couple of times & it fails consistently on the same object, or same type of object, that would be a clue there's something special about it that we need to deal with. I don't have a 17.04 vm right at hand, but I'll try scanning /proc on 16.04 and see what happens on my end.
>
> One other thing that's been known to cause segfaults is the combination of statically linked binaries and remote directory services (NIS, LDAP, AD, etc.). (See issue #11 for a previous example). If that turns out to be the problem, you can either a.) use the RESOLVE_IDS_TO_NAMES=false config file option (introduced in OST 2.4.3.2), or use dynamically linked binaries instead.

Comment: Is there a crash dump file in `/var/crash/`? Read it with `less`, it's a text file.

Comment: yes waltinator, it is: _usr_bin_aide.0.crash

Comment: So it's crashing on /usr/sbin. Are you running as root?. If you don't need to scan /usr/sbin you can just add a "! /usr/sbin ;" line to your policy to exclude it. A segmentation fault can also happen if the process took too much memory and the Kernel kills it. Do you see anything in /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: syslog: Integrity Check Failed: File could not be opened  and  cat /var/crash/_usr_sbin_tripwire.0.uploaded 5e19248b-3a62-11eb-8a34-fa163ee63de6

Comment: Are you running it as root?.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in that problem as well and have a page about it [here](https://linux.m2osw.com/tripwire-init-not-saving-database).

The final solution, in my case, was to edit the `twcfg.txt` file and add the `RESOLVE_IDS_TO_NAMES=false` there.

However, I first commented out a few files: `/proc` & `/dev` and the `/boot` which in my case had some remote mounted folder which tripwire says it doesn't like. These are known to cause issues.

Two other possibilities: a while back, I had a file which was over 2Gb and apparently tripwire was chocking on those. The `/usr/sbin` folder should not have such, though.

One person mentioned that he had a file with -r-------- (400) permissions in his `/usr/sbin` folder. By tweaking his policy file, he hid that file and then it worked. You may be in the same situation. I could not see such a file in my `/usr/sbin` folder, though.

Finally, [Teakwood J Overclutch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287421/tripwire-segmentation-fault-after-upgradiing-to-ubuntu-20-10), who had the same issue, fixed it by recompiling tripwire from the [source](https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source). If nothing else works for you, this may be the solution. I would imagine that the Debian/Ubuntu builds use the same source, but they may have patches, some of which may break something!